# How to get file size on disk on linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I want to find the size of file on disk on linux OS .
I know command to do so:
du -s -h

Is there any way to find it using c/c++ code ?

Comment: My understanding is as hard disk is block device so though i write just 10 bytes to a file, kernel will allocate blocks for the file in terms of block_size .i.e. (512 bytes) . Suppose disk is having total size of 1KB and we have have created 2 files of 10bytes each then disk is full or not ? Am i correct ?

Comment: On Linux most filesystems use a 4 KB block size (that is, each fs block consists of 8 512 byte blocks on the device), so no blocks would fit on a 1KB filesystem (disregarding metadata overhead etc.).

Comment: i know it, i have give 1KB for example only . thanks i got my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, use the `stat(2)` system call:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
...
struct stat statbuf;

if (stat("file.dat", &statbuf) == -1) {
  /* check the value of errno */
}

printf("%9jd", (intmax_t) statbuf.st_size);
```

Comment: Note that to obtain the actual disk size, you'll need to look at st_blocks*512, not st_size

Comment: stat does not give the same size which is give by du -s -h file.dat.

Comment: @Ashish: st_size is the size of the file, that is, the number of bytes it contains. The amount of space the file takes up on the disk is given by st_blocks*512, as Hasturkun mentioned; this is the size that 'du' uses.